# CreateView - Getting a TypeError when trying to save an image upload

Tags: python, django, forms, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to wrap my head around images and [Form handling with class-based views](http://Form%20handling%20with%20class-based%20views). So i'm playing with this simple model. When using CreateView do I have to overwrite it with a custom form using form_class in order to successfully upload/save and image?

I can't figure out why I'm getting this:

```
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
```

The whole thing is barebones, right out of stock.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    cover_image = models.ImageField('hero image', upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('details', args=[str(self.slug)])
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['headline', 'cover_image', 'slug']
```

news/templates/news/post_form.py

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
  </form>
```

Can anyone help me understand?

**As requested**

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

MEDIA_ROOT = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

Comment: Show the full traceback, as well as the MEDIA_ROOT setting.

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: You were right. It was the MEDIA_ROOT. I changed it to MEDIA_ROOT = './media' and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set MEDIA_ROOT to a tuple, but it should be a string.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```